# What does the predicted probability of a logit tell us about the latent value?

Tags: probability, prediction

Imagine a binary logit model under a single latent value $Y_i$ and a threshold $\underline{Y}$, so that $S_i=1$ if $Y_i+e_i>\underline{Y}$ and that $e_i$ is a mean zero error term that this distributed logistic.

Imagine also that we have a measure $\pi_i = P(S_i=1)$.  The question is:

**How much can we learn about $Y_i$ from $\pi_i$?**

In particular, do they have the same distributions or is it just a rank ordering?

Answer (score 0):

If $Y_i \sim \text{logistic}(\mu_i, s)$ then $P(Z_i) = P(Y_i > S) = \text{expit} ((S - \mu_i)/s)$. So the logistic regression model for $\text{logit} ( P(Z_i = 1 | X_i = x) )= \alpha + \beta x$ is a maximum likelihood estimator for $s = 1/\beta$ and $S=-\alpha/\beta$.